# raise an error but the type is valid what to do?

Tags: python, class, exception, typeerror

```
if type(satisfaction) != int or type(satisfaction) != float:
    raise TypeError('The type of satisfaction is not ok')
```

This is the `__init__` of the class

```
def __init__(self, minibar, floor, number,
             guests, clean_level, rank, satisfaction=1.0):
```

those the values

```
rooms = [Room(m, 15, 140, [], 1, 1), Room(m, 12, 101, ["Ronen", "Shir"], 6, 2),
         Room(m, 2, 2, ["Liat"], 1, 1), Room(m, 2, 23, [], 1, 1)]
```

and It raises the error

```
        raise TypeError('The type of satisfaction is not ok')
TypeError: The type of satisfaction is not ok
```

what's the problem?

Comment: When you use `or` that statement will **always be true**... You mean `and`. But please in the future always provide a [mcve]

Comment: Note, this is probably a missapplication of De Morgan's law in your head, which is a common mistake . You did `not ( x or y)` -> `(not x) or (not y)`, but it should be `not ( x or y)` -> `(not x) and (not y)`, when you distribute negation ( `not` ) it flips between a conjunction (`or) and a disjunction (`and`) and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

That is because of the `or` operand

- if variable type is `int`, then `type(satisfaction) != float` is True, `False or True == True` so raise
- if variable type is `float`, then `type(satisfaction) != int` is True, `False or True == True` so raise

You need an `and` : `if type(satisfaction) != int and type(satisfaction) != float:`

---

Also the way to verify type is to use `isinstance`, that accepts multiple types

```
if not isinstance(satisfaction, (int, float)):
    raise TypeError('The type of satisfaction is not ok')
```